# Python Socket Programming - need to do something while listening for connections

Tags: python, sockets

I am in the process of designing some hardware interface with python. what I need to do is as follows,

~initialize the drivers
~start the device 
~create a socket at port 2626 and wait for clients to connect for receiving data
~if any client got connected then send the hello message while serving all other connected client and add this client to the connected client list.
~if any event happened on the device lets say temperature raise is detected then through this event data to all connected clients.
~any connected clients can ask the server for any specific data.

This is my process. I got the device part working great now its printing data to console and for the socket server I have this following code this working fine as I expect.
but what is problem is after calling "run()" its going inside the while loop. its obvious though. when I am listening for new connections I am not able to call any other function.

while listening for connections I should be able to send / recv. any ideas how to do this?

this is my server program which is working fine for listening for connections. while listening you are not allowed to to anything. :(

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import select

class ChatServer:

    def __init__( self, port ):
        self.port = port;

        self.srvsock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
        self.srvsock.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
        self.srvsock.bind( ("", port) )
        self.srvsock.listen( 5 )

        self.descriptors = [self.srvsock]
        print 'Server started on port %s' % port

    def run( self ):
        while 1:
            # Await an event on a readable socket descriptor
            (sread, swrite, sexc) = select.select( self.descriptors, [], [] )
            # Iterate through the tagged read descriptors
            for sock in sread:
                # Received a connect to the server (listening) socket
                if sock == self.srvsock:
                    self.accept_new_connection()
                else:
                    # Received something on a client socket
                    str = sock.recv(100)

                    # Check to see if the peer socket closed
                    if str == '':
                        host,port = sock.getpeername()
                        str = 'Client left %s:%s\r\n' % (host, port)
                        self.broadcast_string( str, sock )
                        sock.close
                        self.descriptors.remove(sock)
                    else:
                        host,port = sock.getpeername()
                        newstr = '[%s:%s] %s' % (host, port, str)
                        self.broadcast_string( newstr, sock )

    def accept_new_connection( self ):
        newsock, (remhost, remport) = self.srvsock.accept()
        self.descriptors.append( newsock )

        newsock.send("You're connected to the Python server\r\n")
        str = 'Client joined %s:%s\r\n' % (remhost, remport)
        self.broadcast_string( str, newsock )

    def broadcast_string( self, str, omit_sock ):
        for sock in self.descriptors:
            if sock != self.srvsock and sock != omit_sock:
                sock.send(str)
        print str,

myServer = ChatServer( 2626 ).run()
```

Thanks in advance for all your help :)

Comment: Use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)?

Comment: @MikeCooper thanks for your suggestion buddy. I am new to python. do you have any samples or could you point to some tutorials for quick start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since twisted is out of question, I suggest using the [socketserver](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/socketserver.html) module.

For an easy start, see this [example](http://danieldandrada.blogspot.com/2007/09/python-socketserverthreadingtcpserver.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your suggestion. I got this working with socketServer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make all sockets [non-blocking](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking).

Comment: @San If you make the sockets (server socket too) non-blocking, then I see no problem with the code you provided.

Comment: I have tried that too. for your ref I am connecting to this from a nodejs script. nodejs is working fine on that way. I need to get rid of the while loop. its halting my program.

Comment: After instantiating the class and calling run() method if i say `print "you can do whatever while I am listening"` this never gets executed.

Comment: @San Ah, I think I know what you mean! One solution is to add a timeout to the `select` call, and if it times out you can do something else and then go back to poll the sockets. Another solution is to put the whole networking loop in a separate thread.

Comment: yes buddy, you got my point. I am new to python just started a week before. I have no Idea of executing the socketserver in a separate thread. and one more point it on the fly if i got any hardware event I  need to push the event data to the socket. any idea on this. Thanks a lot for helping on this buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

An example that shows asynchronous networking with core python is [here](https://github.com/jdavisp3/twisted-intro/blob/master/async-client/get-poetry.py).

Comment: ...or `socketserver` (`SocketServer` for python 2.x)

Comment: @Kimvais are you talking about without using twisted? I have started with python last week only. if you can point some samples I will be more thankful to you.

Comment: @San - if you don't have any _external_ limitations that you can not use twisted - use it. The [tutorial](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/index.html) is a good start.

Comment: @Kimvais - actually I do have such limitations. if it is not possible using pure python, then I have to go for it. twisted looks bulky. these programs I am writing is going to run on less memory devices and not on huge servers. so I prefer doing with pure python.

Comment: @san - You can do asynchronous network programming with core python but it'll take you more work and time, and if you're a beginner in python then you'll have a steep learning curve.

Comment: @san - It's common to mistake Twisted as bulky & impure but, in reality, it's neither. It's full of features but only the code you use is loaded at runtime. Also, the basic stuff you'll need is pure-python. I encourage you to give it a try, it's extremely stable and perfectly suited to your task