# php: pushing new data on server-side event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, linux

Web development being completely new to me, this may be easy to find online but I might lack the technical jargon in this area...

I need to display some data on a linux-device that also runs a webserver, so I figured the easiest way would probably be to do this in a browser. The data might change due to (physical) interaction with the device: it has external push-buttons attached. I need the data on the webpage to change instantly when a button is pressed, so that the user sees the values change immediately when he presses a button.

This might be complete and utter nonsense, but is it possible to have the program that watches for button-presses pipe its output somewhere and have a piece of php respond to this?

A sub-optimal solution would be to have a piece of client-side javascript with a timer that periodically "calls" (?) a piece of php. I don't like this solution because you either reload ad nauseam to minimize delays, or you'll notice lag in the response to the button-presses.

Comment: In short your question is too broad and generic. stackoverflow is really not a consultancy site, also you are not showing any effort of making a script or a program work and asking a fix with a real code sample. Everything you are describing is kind of possible or not but you should really make an effort first and then provide a question with why you are stuck.

Comment: @Bizmate I'm stuck because I don't know if it's possible at all, and if so how. The question is fairly narrow: "is it possible to have the program that watches for button-presses pipe its output somewhere and have a piece of php respond to this?" I'm not asking for opinions. Also, I have mentioned my current solution and the reason I'm not happy with it. Showing my current efforts in the form of code snippets won't help anyone.

Comment: Javascript can and does watch for events within the browser - theoretically the `button presses` to which you allude could be monitored by javascript - but the vague nature of the question makes answers equally vague. But, basically it is possible to do.

Comment: @RamRaider Could you tell me what's vague? I'll edit and clarify where possible.

Comment: A little help on the above ... if your webserver runs php it is possible, you can code a web application that loads and uses javascript like RamRaider suggested. code snippets and examples is what every entry includes on stackoverflow see - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... also you question is about mobile application development. PHP is not related at all and i have not seen it applied on a mobile device. Usually apps talk to a remote webserver running php.

Comment: @Bizmate Where did I say anything about a mobile device?

Comment: Comment corrected to remove mobile . You can code a web application that loads and uses javascript like RamRaider suggested or just submit your form and let php handle it. Code snippets and examples is what every entry includes on stackoverflow see - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: the question is vague in that you don't specify the type of data that is to be display, where it comes from ( db, text file, remote site, api, domain ), what the webserver is doing, what the server-side events are, what flavour of webserver it is ( apache is most likely ), whether the user interacts with the data - if you were to explicitly state the nature of the problem others might be able to see the wood for the trees as it were and offer proper guidance ( though generally a question such as this is would be considered "off-topic" ) I'm not trying to be obtuse, you just need to clarify it.

Comment: @RamRaider Type of data: there's no such thing as type of data. Where it comes from: from an external program (which I mentioned). Whether the user interacts: it is displayed so no, or yes depending on how one defines interaction. I'm removing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use socket programming. Usually used in chat servers to send data to client without refreshing. 
http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php
This should help

In this question the p asker tries to do the same u are trying, push data on some external event
[Python Socket Programming - need to do something while listening for connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306412/python-socket-programming-need-to-do-something-while-listening-for-connections)

Comment: Thank you! Finally someone that understands what I'm asking ;-)